# How to integrate a plotter, which has a slider, into a PySide6 GUI?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, slider, qtwidgets

I have a simple plotter, that has 2 subplots and a slider, which is used to change the xLim and yLim of the 2 subplots.
When I call the plotter calss from "main", it works fine, but when I call it from a callback function of a button of a PySide6 GUI, the Slider doesn't move.
so, how to integrate a plotter, which has a slider, into a PySide6 GUI?

I tried the following code and I excpect, that when I press the plot button a figure shows, where the slider moves.

```
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QApplication
from matplotlib.widgets import Slider
from PySide6.QtCore import Slot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys


class MyPlotter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.t = np.arange(0, 10.001, 0.001)
        amplitude = 5
        frequency = 3  # Hz
        self.y1 = amplitude * np.sin(2 * np.pi * frequency * self.t)
        self.y2 = self.y1 * amplitude * np.exp(-1 * self.t)
        self.error = np.subtract(self.y1, self.y2)

        self.figure = plt.figure()

        self.subplot1 = self.figure.add_subplot(211)
        [line1] = self.subplot1.plot(self.t, self.y1, "r", label="a*sin(2*pi*f*t), a=5, f=3")
        [line2] = self.subplot1.plot(self.t, self.y2, "b", label="a^2*sin(2*pi*f*t)*e-t, a=5, f=3")
        self.subplot1.legend()
        self.subplot1.set_xlabel("t[s]")
        self.subplot1.set_ylabel("Signals")

        self.subplot2 = self.figure.add_subplot(212)
        [line3] = self.subplot2.plot(self.t, self.error, "g", label="red - blue")
        self.subplot2.legend()
        self.subplot2.set_xlabel("t[s]")
        self.subplot2.set_ylabel("Error")

        self.figure.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.25)
        # Define an axes area and draw a slider in it
        # matplotlib.figure.Figure.add_axes((left, bottom, width, height))
        time_slider_ax = self.figure.add_axes((0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.03), facecolor="lightgoldenrodyellow")
        time_slider = Slider(time_slider_ax, "Time", 0, self.t[-1], valinit=0, valstep=self.t[1], initcolor="none")
        time_slider.on_changed(self._sliderOnChanged)
        plt.show()

    def _sliderOnChanged(self, val):
        index = np.where(self.t == val)[0][0]
        data1 = self.y1[index:]
        data2 = self.y2[index:]
        data3 = self.error[index:]
        self.subplot1.set_xlim(val, self.t[-1])
        self.subplot1.set_ylim(min(np.min(data1), np.min(data2)), max(np.max(data1), np.max(data2)))
        self.subplot2.set_xlim(val, self.t[-1])
        self.subplot2.set_ylim(np.min(data3), np.max(data3))
        self.figure.canvas.draw_idle()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.pushButtonPlot = QPushButton("Plot")
        self.pushButtonPlot.clicked.connect(self._onPushButtonPlotClicked)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButtonPlot)

    @Slot()
    def _onPushButtonPlotClicked(self):
        MyPlotter()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    mw = MainWindow()
    mw.show()
    executed = app.exec()
    sys.exit(executed)
```